# How to check if a Ruby object is a Boolean

Tags: ruby, typechecking

I can't seem to check if an object is a boolean easily.  Is there something like this in Ruby?

```
true.is_a?(Boolean)
false.is_a?(Boolean)
```

Right now I'm doing this and would like to shorten it:

```
some_var = rand(1) == 1 ? true : false
(some_var.is_a?(TrueClass) || some_var.is_a?(FalseClass))
```

Comment: Similar: [check-whether-a-variable-is-a-string-in-ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749416/check-whether-a-variable-is-a-string-in-ruby?rq=1)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
# checking whether foo is a boolean
!!foo == foo
```

Comment: class X; def !; self end end ;
x = X.new ;
!!x == x #=> true

Comment: Yes, that's called duck typing and a core principle of OOP. I think it's a feature.

Comment: The problem with it is that "if it walks like duck" does not imply "it quacks like duck". Correspondingly `!!pseudo_bool == pseudo_bool` does not imply `pseudo_bool & true == pseudo_bool` for example.

Comment: Right, if there would be an agreed upon method to check this, like with `to_ary`, then it would be easier. However, I don't think this argument really counts. People could also override `is_a?`. In that case the only real way would be to use `Module#===`, as it does not call any method on the object in question. Which in turn is a violation of OOP, as all you should do is sending methods.

Comment: Short doesn't necessarily mean simple.  By which I mean, wtf is that?

Comment: Turns foo into a boolean, checks if that's the same as foo.

Comment: it's cryptic, but really no alternative comes close

Comment: I don't know about this answer... If foo = "" then `!!foo == foo` return true.

Comment: @Dan No it doesn't. If `foo = ""`, then `!!foo` is true, and true does not equal an empty string.

Comment: Note that double negation is considered bad style by some checkers (like [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop)).

Comment: since a boolean column can be nil, and this doesn't work for nil, is there a better way?

Comment: @jpwynn what makes you think this doesn't work for nil? `nil != false` so this works just fine for nil

Comment: Considering `foo` as a string, it considers it as a Boolean which is not true. Am I right?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi: `foo = "bar"; !!foo == foo #=> false`

Comment: -1: This does not check if `foo` is a boolean, this _converts the value_ of `foo` into a boolean. That is, this is not the same as `foo.is_a?(TrueClass) || foo.is_a?(FalseClass)

Comment: as @EricDuminil mentioned, this does not work well on strings `foo = "bar"; !!foo == foo #=> false` : -1

Comment: @PavanKumarV: The code is not really readable, but it does work on strings. It returns `false`, which is correct. A String isn't a boolean.

Answer (score 151):

I find this to be concise and self-documenting:

```
[true, false].include? foo
```

If using Rails or ActiveSupport, you can even do a direct query using [`in?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#in-questionmark)

```
foo.in? [true, false]
```

Checking against all possible values isn't something I'd recommend for floats, but feasible when there are only two possible values!

Comment: best answer by far, although I also liked `foo == true or foo == false` that somebody put in a comment.

Comment: I like this because it is less cryptic in intent than the `!!foo == foo`.

Comment: Downright pythonic! Definitely the most semantic answer here by far.

Answer (score 94):

There is no `Boolean` class in Ruby, the only way to check is to do what you're doing (comparing the object against `true` and `false` or the class of the object against `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`). Can't think of why you would need this functionality though, can you explain? :)

If you *really* need this functionality however, you can hack it in:

```
module Boolean; end
class TrueClass; include Boolean; end
class FalseClass; include Boolean; end

true.is_a?(Boolean) #=> true
false.is_a?(Boolean) #=> true
```

Comment: trying to do typecasting based on the current value.

Comment: 'Why would you ever what that?' (and derivatives) is just one of the most annoying questions an engineer can make another :)

Comment: +1 because I can use this in rspec like: `expect(some_method?(data)).to be_a(Boolean)`

Comment: Other case when need to check type, is when you implement database adapter and need wrap strings with `"quotes"` but not numbers and booleans

Comment: I'd say that being able to check the type of a variable is such a fundamentally valuable thing for a programming language, and is super important when validating user input. The fact that it's not supported without these odd hacks is... confusing to me.. Doing some research it seems to be that Ruby's way of implementing dynamic typing means there is no way to derive the type. Javascript doesn't have this issue, so I guess there is some larger story behind this..

Answer (score 29):

As stated above there is no boolean class just TrueClass and FalseClass however you can use any object as the subject of if/unless and everything is true except instances of FalseClass and nil

Boolean tests return an instance of the FalseClass or TrueClass

```
(1 > 0).class #TrueClass
```

The following monkeypatch to Object will tell you whether something is an instance of TrueClass or FalseClass

```
class Object
  def boolean?
    self.is_a?(TrueClass) || self.is_a?(FalseClass) 
  end
end
```

Running some tests with irb gives the following results

```
?> "String".boolean?
=> false
>> 1.boolean?
=> false
>> Time.now.boolean?
=> false
>> nil.boolean?
=> false
>> true.boolean?
=> true
>> false.boolean?
=> true
>> (1 ==1).boolean?
=> true
>> (1 ==2).boolean?
=> true
```

Comment: Simpler just to write `self == true or self == false`. Those are the only instances of TrueClass and FalseClass.

Comment: @chuck that returns the same results except for Time.now.boolean? which returns nil. Any idea why?

Comment: Defining a class check on self in the method is somewhat not oop. You should define two versions of `boolean`, one for TrueClass/FalseClass and one for Object.

Comment: The reason is that a bug in the version of `Time#==` in Ruby 1.8 causes a comparison to non-Time values to return nil rather than false.

Answer (score 22):

If your code can sensibly be written as a case statement, this is pretty decent:

```
case mybool
when TrueClass, FalseClass
  puts "It's a bool!"
else
  puts "It's something else!"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

An object that is a boolean will either have a class of TrueClass or FalseClass so the following one-liner should do the trick

```
mybool = true
mybool.class == TrueClass || mybool.class == FalseClass
=> true
```

The following would also give you true/false boolean type check result

```
mybool = true    
[TrueClass, FalseClass].include?(mybool.class)
=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

So try this out  `(x == true) ^ (x == false)` note you need the parenthesis but this is more beautiful and compact.

It even passes the suggested like "cuak" but not a "cuak"... `class X; def !; self end end ; x = X.new; (x == true) ^ (x == false)`

***Note***: See that this is so basic that you can use it in other languages too, that doesn't provide a "thing is boolean".

***Note 2***: Also you can use this to say thing is one of??: `"red", "green", "blue"` if you `add more XORS`... or say this thing is one of??: `4, 5, 8, 35`.

Comment: Why XOR? Why not OR?

Answer (score 3):

This gem adds a Boolean class to Ruby with useful methods.

https://github.com/RISCfuture/boolean

Use:

```
require 'boolean'
```

Then your

```
true.is_a?(Boolean)
false.is_a?(Boolean)
```

will work exactly as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

No. Not like you have your code. There isn't any class named Boolean. Now with all the answers you have you should be able to create one and use it. You do know how to create classes don't you? I only came here because I was just wondering this idea myself. Many people might say "Why? You have to just know how Ruby uses Boolean". Which is why you got the answers you did. So thanks for the question. Food for thought. Why doesn't Ruby have a Boolean class?

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Boolean
```

Keep in mind that Objects do not have types. They are classes. Objects have data. So that's why when you say data types it's a bit of a misnomer.

Also try rand 2 because rand 1 seems to always give 0. rand 2 will give 1 or 0
click run a few times here.
https://repl.it/IOPx/7

Although I wouldn't know how to go about making a Boolean class myself. I've experimented with it but...

```
class Boolean < TrueClass
  self
end

true.is_a?(Boolean) # => false
false.is_a?(Boolean) # => false
```

At least we have that class now but who knows how to get the right values?