# Check whether a variable is a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, idioms, typechecking

Is there anything more idiomatic than the following?

```
foo.class == String
```

Answer (score 257, accepted):

I think you are looking for `instance_of?`. `is_a?` and `kind_of?` will return true for instances from derived classes.

```
class X < String
end

foo = X.new

foo.is_a? String         # true
foo.kind_of? String      # true
foo.instance_of? String  # false
foo.instance_of? X       # true
```

Comment: Without knowing the question's intent, I'd say for most real-world programming situations, `is_a?` is actually the more appropriate idiom to use (and often a duck-typing check like Andrew Grimm mentions is even better). A strict class comparison is usually a code smell. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Quick aside: if you use this in conditional logic you need to use parentheses; eg, if foo.is_a?(String) && ...

Comment: As expected, this approach will work not only with `String`, but also with `Integer` and `Float`. Does it also work for `Decimal`? (the sublime text interpreter highlights the syntax differently for `Decimal` which makes me suspicious)

Answer (score 35):

You can do:

```
foo.instance_of?(String)
```

And the more general:

```
foo.kind_of?(String)
```

Comment: [davidchambers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312785/davidchambers) and [steenslag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290394/steenslag) noted that `kind_of?` is a synonym for [`is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_object.html#Object.is_a_qm). Unfortunately, including these comments as discussed for example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254530/4575793) was rejected.

Answer (score 33):

A more duck-typing approach would be to say

```
foo.respond_to?(:to_str)
```

`to_str` indicates that an object's class may not be an actual descendant of the String, but the object itself is very much string-like (stringy?).

Comment: Cool. In this case I happen to know that `foo` will either be `true`, `false`, or a vanilla string, but it's good to learn more general solutions.

Comment: combine this with a to_s call after checking if the object responds_to it, and you got yourself a string!

Comment: @seanmakesgames Did you mean `to_str`, or `to_s`? The two are slightly different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182052/to-s-vs-to-str-and-to-i-to-a-to-h-vs-to-int-to-ary-to-hash-in-ruby Re: andrew's comment.

Answer (score 8):

```
foo.instance_of? String
```

or

```
foo.kind_of? String
```

if you you only care if it is derrived from `String` somewhere up its inheritance chain

Comment: Isn't that a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749428/4575793)?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, `Class` defines the method `===` to test whether an object is an instance of that class.

- `o.class` class of `o`.
- `o.instance_of? c` determines whether `o.class == c`
- `c === o` for a class or module, determine if `o.is_a? c` (`String === "s"` returns `true`)
- `o.is_a? c` Is `o` an instance of `c` or any of it's subclasses?
- `o.kind_of? c` synonym for `is_a?`

Comment: Note the subtle difference between `==` and `===`.

Answer (score -1):

I think a better way is to create some predicate methods.
This will also save your "Single Point of Control".

```
class Object
 def is_string?
   false
 end
end

class String
 def is_string?
   true
 end
end

print "test".is_string? #=> true
print 1.is_string?      #=> false
```

The more duck typing way ;)

Comment: what's wrong with `"string".is_a?(String)`. It seems like you're reinventing the wheel. There's also `class`, `instance_of`, `kind_of`, etc... Bad idea to monkey patch the `Object` class, not to mention it's needless.

Comment: I totally agree with you :) If your focus is only on primitve types and you know that your project requirements related to primitive types will never change (ok its usually the case ;) ) youre fine.  But in a case where requirements change its better to have a "Single Point of Control". For example in your project environment you have a lot of pre checks (1000 and up).  `pre_check("test".is_string?)`  
  Now your project requirement will change and every String with three characters or more is no longer defined as String (i know its unusual ;))
  Now you can change your own method easily.