# to_s vs. to_str (and to_i/to_a/to_h vs. to_int/to_ary/to_hash) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, methods

I'm learning Ruby and I've seen a couple of methods that are confusing me a bit, particularly `to_s` vs `to_str` (and similarly, `to_i`/`to_int`, `to_a`/`to_ary`, & `to_h`/`to_hash`). What I've read explains that the shorter form (e.g. `to_s`) are for explicit conversions while the longer form are for implicit conversions.

I don't really understand how `to_str` would actually be used. Would something other than a String ever define `to_str`? Can you give a practical application for this method?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Note first that all of this applies to each pair of “short” (e.g. `to_s`/`to_i`/`to_a`/`to_h`) vs. “long” (e.g. `to_str`/`to_int`/`to_ary`/`to_hash`) coercion methods in Ruby (for their respective types) as they all have the same semantics.

---

They have different meanings. You should not implement `to_str` unless your object *acts* like a string, rather than just being *representable* by a string. The only core class that implements `to_str` is String itself.

From *Programming Ruby* (quoted from [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161201181048/http://briancarper.net/blog/98.html), which is worth reading all of):

> [`to_i` and `to_s`] are not particularly strict: if an object has some kind of decent representation as a string, for example, it will probably have a `to_s` method… [`to_int` and `to_str`] are strict conversion functions: you implement them only if [your] object can naturally be used every place a string or an integer could be used.

[Older Ruby documentation from the Pickaxe](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.to_str) has this to say:

> Unlike `to_s`, which is supported by almost all classes, `to_str` is normally implemented only by those classes that act like strings.

For example, in addition to [Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-to_int), both [Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-to_int) & [Numeric](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-to_int) implement `to_int` (`to_i`'s equivalent of `to_str`) because both of them can readily substituted for an Integer (they are all actually numbers). Unless your class has a similarly tight relationship with String, you should not implement `to_str`.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. But in a practical sense, what does that mean "those classes that act like strings?" Does that mean they implement the same methods as Strings? And what else would to_str return other than self if the object already acts like a string?

Comment: @JeffStorey Yes. Unless your class can be substituted for/by a String, you should not implement `to_str`. String's implementation of `to_s` and `to_str` do just that: return themselves. Implementing `to_str` is a way of validating that you act like a String. Many core methods use `to_str` in this way. The blog post I quoted from is worth reading `:)`.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. I did read that post and I was still a little unclear. Is there ever a time where you might implement to_str? That's the part I'm really confused about...I can't think of a practical example offhand.

Comment: @JeffStorey Unless you're creating a class that's just like a String and implements at a minimum all the methods it does, no. Of course in this case you're likely to have subclasses String anyway, and get it for free. A good example of when to do so is Ruby's numerics: Float, Integer, & Numeric all implement `to_int` (`to_i`'s "`to_str`" equivalent), because they can be substituted for each other readily.

Comment: Jeff, in theory, you *could* implement a `to_str` method which returned an actual String. That would make your class usable everywhere where a String is; in any case where a String was needed, `to_str` would be invoked, and the resulting String used. So you could mix instances of your custom class together with Strings and work with them homogenously. Would you really want to do that? It's completely up to you! Ruby is a language which gives the programmer a *lot* of flexibility to "bend" the language any way you want. YOU decide how best to use that flexibility.

Comment: Andrew, that's a really good example with the numerics. That helps to clarify.

Comment: Take a look at the Ruby koans _about_to_str_ example for some more insight.

Comment: Is there similar for Floats?

Comment: @thomthom Nope: `Float.instance_methods.grep(/to_/) #=> [:to_c, :to_enum, :to_f, :to_i, :to_int, :to_r, :to_s]`.

Comment: If you can only use `to_str` when it acts like a string, then what is the point of using it? I may have missed the explanation, but maybe the explanation needs to be more explicit in the purpose/utility of using `to_str`

Comment: does symbol have short and long versions of conversion coercion methods?

Comment: @gwho No, there’s not (there’s just `to_sym`, which his arguably the “long” version since it’s only on String & Symbol). Probably because Symbol is really special, and you likely want to coerce-to/act-like a String instead. But I’m just guessing there.

Answer (score 24):

To understand if you should use/implement `to_s`/`to_str`, let's look at some exemples. It is revealing to consider **when these method fail**.

```
1.to_s              # returns "1"
Object.new.to_s     # returns "#<Object:0x4932990>"
1.to_str            # raises NoMethodError
Object.new.to_str   # raises NoMethodError
```

As we can see, `to_s` is happy to turn **any object** into a string. On the other hand, `to_str` **raises an error** when its parameter does not look like a string.

---

Now let us look at `Array#join`.

```
[1,2].join(',')     # returns "1,2"
[1,2].join(3)       # fails, the argument does not look like a valid separator.
```

It is useful that `Array#join` converts to string the items in the array (whatever they really are) before joining them, so `Array#join` calls `to_s` on them.

However, the separator is supposed to be a string -- **someone calling `[1,2].join(3)` is likely to be making a mistake**. This is why `Array#join` calls `to_str` on the separator.

---

The same principle seems to hold for the other methods. Consider `to_a`/`to_ary` on a hash:

```
{1 => 2}.to_a      # returns [[1, 2]], an array that describes the hash
{1 => 2}.to_ary    # fails, because a hash is not really an array.
```

In summary, here is how I see it:

- call `to_s`  to get a string that describes the object.
- call `to_str` to verify that an object really acts like a string.
- implement `to_s` when you can build a string that describes your object.
- implement `to_str` when your object can fully behave like a string.

I think a case when you could implement `to_str` yourself is maybe a `ColoredString` class -- a string that has a color attached to it. If it seems clear to you that passing a colored comma to `join` is not a mistake and should result in `"1,2"` (even though that string would not be colored), then *do* implement `to_str` on ColoredString.

Answer (score 0):

[Zverok](https://zverok.github.io/blog/2016-01-18-implicit-vs-expicit.html) has a great easily understandable article about when to use what (explained with to_h and to_hash).

It has to do whether your Object implementing those methods can be converted to a string
 -> use `to_s`
or it is a type of some (enhanced) string
 -> use `to_str`

---

I've seen a meaningful usage of `to_hash` in practice for the Configuration class in the gem ['configuration'](https://rubygems.org/gems/configuration) ([GitHub](https://github.com/ahoward/configuration) and [Configuration.rb](https://github.com/ahoward/configuration/blob/master/lib/configuration.rb))

It represents -- as the name says -- the provided configuration, which in fact is a kind of hash (with additional features), rather than being convertible to one.