# Defining `to_i` so that it is called implicitly

Tags: ruby, implicit-conversion

Defining `to_s` on a class works as I expect:

```
class Foo
  def to_s
    "Joe"
  end 
end

f = Foo.new
"hello #{f}" # => "hello Joe"
```

I attempt to utilize `to_i` and expect it to work in a similar fashion. I expect that, by defining `to_i` to be a number, then anywhere a number is expected, the object will return that number in the place of the object; in a situation like the following, I expect it to return the integer `5`. Instead, it raises an error:

```
class Foo
  def to_i
    0
  end
end

f = Foo.new
5 + f # => TypeError: Foo can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

What does defining `to_i` enable?  How do you utilize it? Can I implicitly represent this object as an integer and return `0` just like the object implicitly returns the string `"Joe"`?

Comment: This will work if you implement `to_int`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182052/to-s-vs-to-str-and-to-i-to-a-to-h-vs-to-int-to-ary-to-hash-in-ruby

Comment: @matt would you mind elaborating a bit more?  I did this: `def to_int; 0; end` and it errored out just the same as the `to_i` definition above.

Comment: @matt: No, it's `coerce`: `class Foo; def coerce(n) [0, n] end end`.

Comment: @cremno Yes, you’re right, sorry. `to_int` will work for other things like using it as an array index, but you need `coerce` for arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial difference between the two cases is that string interpolation `"#{}"` calls `to_s` implicitly while `Fixnum#+` does not call `to_i` implicitly on its argument.

Defining `to_i` only lets you call it (explicitly). Whether or not it is called implicitly depends on where that is used. There is nothing you can do to make `to_i` be called implicitly just by defining `to_i`. If you really want to do it, you have to modify `Fixnum#+`.